# Finding a function to scale $x$-axis to fit points to sine curve.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Before trying to formulate the problem let's consider the thoughts behind the question. Consider that we have measured the temperature at times $0,~1,~\dots,n-1$. We now want to re-scale the time axis so that the measured values can be perfectly fitted to a sine curve. We want to construct a scaling function which can be reused for fitting any such sequence of measurements to a sine curve by adapting a real parameter $s$.

Assume that $y$ is a sequence of $n$ real numbers: $y_0,~y_1,~\dots,~y_{n-1}$

Assume that all elements $y_i$ of $y$ satisfies $-1 \le y_i \le 1$

Given $f(x) = \sin(x+\sin^{-1}y_0)$ (or as pointed out possibly $f(x) = sin(x + \pi - sin^{-1} y_0)$)

Find $g(s, i)$ satisfying $g(s, 0)=0$ and $f(g(s, i)) = y_i$ where $s$ is real number dependent on $y$. The function $g(s, i)$ should not be directly dependent on $y$ or any element $y_i$. It should only be dependent on the real $s$ which in turn can be dependent on $y$.

Is this possible? If so, what is $g(s, i)$?

Comment: You'll probably need to allow both $f(x) = \sin(x+\sin^{-1}y_0)$ and $f(x) = \sin(x+\pi-\sin^{-1}y_0)$. Also, the way you've formulated the problem, the function $g(s,i) = \sin^{-1}y_i-\sin^{-1}y_0$ (which is independent of $s$) satisfies $f(g(s,i))=y_i$. If that answer isn't acceptable for your purposes, what properties do you need $g(s,i)$ to have?

Comment: Your questions highlight something important that I failed to mention in the original post. The function $g(s, i)$ should not be directly dependent on $y$ or any element $y_i$. It should only be dependent on the real $s$ which in turn can be dependent on $y$.

Allowing $f(x) = sin(x + \pi - sin^{-1} y_0)$ is fine.